# How can i implement onItemSelected on MaterialBetterSpinner library

Tags: android, spinner

I have implemented the following library spinner in my app i.e from xml

```
<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/insurer_code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_insurer_code"
        android:textColor="@color/smart_primary"
        android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint"
        app:met_floatingLabel="normal" />
```

and java code

```
public class testActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), "Selected: " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

but the onItemSelected doesn't fire up when an item is selected from the menu. Any guidance on how to successfully implement the above library will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

just simple add this one and works like a charm!! `

```
materialDesignSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        materialDesignSpinner.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                quantity=materialDesignSpinner.getText().toString();
Log.d("value",quantity);

            }
        });
```

`

Answer (score 3):

The setOnItemSelectedListener does not work, because the Material/BetterSpinner is a EditText with auto-complete. Not a really Spinner.
you can see the answer here: 
https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner/issues/42

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code.

```
MaterialBetterSpinner MBS = (MaterialBetterSpinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner);
MBS.addTextChangedListener(new myTextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  Log.e("Text",MBS.getText().toString()); 
}
});
```

Create a myTextWatcher class then copy paste the code below.

```
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
public class myTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
public class DropDownList extends MaterialBetterSpinner {

    private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener;

    public DropDownList(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DropDownList(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public DropDownList(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i,   long l) {
        super.onItemClick(adapterView, view, i, l);

        if (listener != null)
            listener.onItemSelected(adapterView, view, i, l);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener l) {
        super.setOnItemSelectedListener(l);

        listener = l;
    }
```

}