# How to add if statement to MaterialBetterSpinner android

Tags: android

I use (MaterialBetterSpinner) to display options 1 or 0

It works well but I need to add a command to each choice.

For example:

if I choose the value 0, show me the message

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You are select 0 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If you choose 1, show me the message

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You are select 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

this is full code

```
  materialBetterSpinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner)rootView. findViewById(R.id.material_spinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adaptermatr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, SPINNER_DATA);
            materialBetterSpinner.setAdapter(adaptermatr);
```

```
    String[] SPINNER_DATA = {"1", "0"};

    MaterialBetterSpinner materialBetterSpinner;
```

I try like that but not working:

```
materialBetterSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        if (materialBetterSpinner.equals(0)) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            parseJSON();
        } else if (materialBetterSpinner.equals("1")) {
            pars();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});
```

If anyone knows the solution  help me please

Comment: Can it be materialBetterSpinner.getText().equals("0") instead of materialBetterSpinner.equals(0) ?

Comment: No it does not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43069477/8956604

Comment: Ok brother  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { its work but how I can add if condition in it ? because I have to option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (s.toString().equals("0")) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        parseJSON();
    } else{
        pars();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```